# Custom ActionLink with support of domain routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have application that accepts four different types of routes. Keyword link is the link of specific page and keyword user is the user that is the owner of the page.

Custom ActionLink should generate links on page depending on route taken to get there. Those links can be:

- http://localhost/SiteEdit/user/link
- http://www.domain.com/SiteEdit/user/link
- http://user.domain.com/link
- http://www.user.com/link

It has to create absolute links, because if relative links are used user can enter the page with http://localhost/SiteEdit/user and the default page will be displayed but if clicked on link it would become http://localhost/SiteEdit/link.

thnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link should help:

http://hanssens.com/2009/asp-net-mvc-subdomain-routing/

> > Update:
> >     Try this gist: https://gist.github.com/RyannosaurusRex/4145948

Comment: Link appears to be broken. Not sure if it exists in google cache or anywhere else.